# How to set array value in the jsonobject

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I am getting the array values as

I need to construct the object as jsonObject.

So I have added like below but the returning object as an error.

How can I add the array as expected in the users.

Note: Here I am sending the users in array from a fragment to set the values in my payload

```
private String mUserArray; //value =["user1", "user2"]

mUserArray is added in the constructor.

final JsonArray array = new JsonArray();
array.add(mUserArray1);
final JsonObject jo = new JsonObject();
jo.addProperty("type", "value")
jo.add("usernames" , array); // If i set the userarray it failed to convert Added like this as well//new JsonPrimitive(mUserArray1)

return jo;
```

Expected Result:
`{"type": "value", "usernames":["user1", "user2"]}`

Actual Result:
`{"type":"value","usernames":"[\"user1\", \"user2\"]"}`

Comment: Can you please clarify which JSON implementation and programming language this is? I assume it is GSON in Java or am I mistaken? And what do you mean by "mUserArray is added in the constructor"? Do you create a new `JsonArray` from the `String`? Please give the code for that.

Comment: User list in array. ArrayList<Object> selectedList= value.getSelected();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like that you added the `usernames` property as a string literal rather than as a JSON array. You can construct a `JsonArray` of strings from a Java array the following way.

```
    String[] userArray = {"user1", "user2"};

    JsonArray userJsonArray = new JsonArray();

    for(String user: userArray){
        userJsonArray.add(new JsonPrimitive(user));
    }

    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
    jsonObject.addProperty("type", "value");
    jsonObject.add("usernames", userJsonArray);
```

Note that `JsonObject::addProperty` only adds primitives to the JSON object rather than arrays or objects.

Comment: It shows Cannot access '<init>': it is package-private in 'JsonPrimitive'. How t solve it

Comment: @RaJ which GSON and Java version do you use? And do you use an exact copy of this code?